# Sharded Jedis - When should I call pool.destroy()?

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I'm helping maintain an app that uses Jedis to connect to Sharded Redis.

The app I'm working with keeps an instance of the **ShardedJedisPool** in a service, to keep reusing it over multiple requests.

I was [reviewing the docs on Sharded Jedis](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/wiki/AdvancedUsage#wiki-shardedjedis) and [noticed the following comment](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/wiki/AdvancedUsage#wiki-3-disconnect--returnressource):

> Forgetting pool.destroy keeps the connection open until timeout is
>   reached.

Our app isn't calling **pool.destroy()** anywhere. Should we be calling **pool.destroy()** on every request? And I guess, creating a new pool on every request as well? Or can my pool stay alive for the lifetime of my service, and only call **pool.destroy()** in the **finalize** method of the service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `ShardedJedisPool` and `JedisPool` are intended to be created only once for the entire life of the application. And you destroy them when the application shutsdown.
Both `ShardedJedisPool` and `JedisPool` are thread-safe, meanning that it is safe to use the same instance across threads (in your case requests) and get an instance of `ShardedJedis` or `Jedis`. After using ShardedJedis or Jedis, you should return them to the pool, or else the pool will get exhausted (depending on how you configured it).

Comment: How do I apply this answer to a web app using Spring? Where should pool.destroy() be called in this case?